# Log of installations in XP?

Tags: windows-xp, logging, windows-installer, event-log

Does XP keep a log of application installations with version numbers of the installations?

I would like to know when MSI based installations took place and what versions were installed.

Answer (score 1):

Check this out. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/223300
You need to turn on logging, so you may not be able to get that info for previous installs, but you can certainly get it for new installs from now on.

You can get a list of installed software (but not specifically MSI installed) by querying WMIC.

wmic product get /format:csv > Software_%Computername%.csv

Answer (score 0):

List 64 bit App:

```
powershell gci hklm:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall -rec^|gp^|select DisplayName,ReleaseType,DisplayVersion^|sort DisplayName^|FT -Au|findstr [\s]>>C:\App64.txt
```

Output:

```
DisplayName                                                                                  ReleaseType     DisplayVersion 
64 Bit HP CIO Components Installer                                                                           7.2.4          
Adobe PDF iFilter 11 for 64-bit platforms                                                                    11.0.00        
Debugging Tools for Windows (x64)                                                                            6.12.2.633     
GDR 5069 for SQL Server Analysis Services 2005 (64-bit) ENU (KB2716429)                      GDR             9.4.5069       
...
```

List 32 bit App:

```
powershell gci hklm:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall -rec^|gp^|select DisplayName,ReleaseType,DisplayVersion^|sort DisplayName^|FT -Au|findstr [\s]>>C:\App32.txt
```